# Eclipse c++ configuration error

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Im getting the following error when i try to create a simple helloWorld C++ project in eclipse. Please note that i have MinGW, msys and my environment variables set up right. Im using Windows 7 and the 32bit Eclipse Juno.

Error:

Error 127 occurred while running autoreconf      HelloWorld            -1      Configure Problem

The error occurs as soon as i create the project. I had another c++ compiler on my machine (DevC++) and thought this might be causing the problem, so i removed it..However im still getting the same error. Please help

Thanks